# React prevent component re render on click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've spent a good bit of time trying to figure out how to stop my component from re-rendering `this.createColorBlocks()` in the `render()` method. I've read posts talking about pure components and the `shouldComponentUpdate` method but I've been yet unable to figure out an approach that would allow me to add the generated array to state and then to map over that once its updated.

Am I on the right track? Is having the createColorMethod method being fired inside the render method causing the entire component to rerender? How can I avoid this?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ColorScheme from "color-scheme";
import uuidv1 from "uuid/v1";
import ColorBar from "../ColorBar/ColorBar";
import "./PalettePicker.css";

export default class PalettePicker extends Component {
  state = {
    hue: null,
    colorScheme: null,
    variation: "pastel",
    colors: [],
    editable: false
  };

  // shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  //   return this.props.color !== nextProps.color;
  // }

  toggleEditable = () => {
    const toggle = this.state.editable;
    this.setState({ editable: !toggle });
  };

  generateRandomHue = () => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (360 + 1));
  };

  generateColors = () => {
    // The possible values are 'mono', 'contrast', 'triade', 'tetrade', and 'analogic'
    const { hue, colorScheme, variation } = this.state;
    const { pColorScheme = "mono" } = this.props;
    const scheme = new ColorScheme();
    scheme
      .from_hue(hue || this.generateRandomHue())
      .scheme(colorScheme || pColorScheme)
      .variation(variation);
    // return scheme.colors();
    const colors = scheme.colors().map(color => {
      return "#" + color;
    });
    return colors;
  };

  createColorBlocks = () => {
    const generatedColors = this.generateColors();
    const colors = generatedColors.splice(0, this.props.totalColors);
    console.log(colors);
    return colors.map((color, i) => {
      const uuid = uuidv1();
      return (
        <ColorBar
          color={color}
          vRotate={this.props.vRotate}
          number={i}
          key={uuid}
        />
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    const editBlockStyles = {
      transform: "translateY(-15px)"
    };
    const colors = this.createColorBlocks();
    return (
      <section className="PalettePicker">
        <div className="colors-section">{colors}</div>
        <div className="button-bar">
// I believe this onClick event is causing the rerender.
          <button className="primary-btn" onClick={this.toggleEditable}>
            Edit Colors
          </button>
          <button className="primary-btn">Save</button>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: well you are going to create all of the color sets on each render cycle. maybe do that creation in a `didMount` and then set that data into the state, this way you only generate the data once. I wouldn't worry about render running again if you aren't doing the data creation there. Also **dont use a uuid** as the key of your elements. You want consistent keys, generally a unique id is good as long as its relational to the data. Meaning, if each render cycle you generate a UUID for each element then react thinks its a different element to render. You need it to not change all the time.

Comment: ```https://www.npmjs.com/package/why-did-you-update``` might help in finding additional information of where the update got triggered.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thank you for the advice, i moved it out and have it working now following your suggestion. I was worried that having a map in the render method would trigger a rerender but that doesnt seem to be the case. Also, I appreciate the uuid tip, I was never really sure if that was being used properly as it did manage to silence the react warning. I'll look around for resources for how to properly set up keys. Mohan, thank you for the link, i'll definitely look into that.

Comment: Great! happy I could help :D please feel free to reach out if you have more questions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each state update in react causes a re-render, and as your `onClick` toggles the `editable` flag, the component will re-render on each button click. If you don't want colors to be regenerated each time, you need to move that function out of the `render()` (for example, to the `componentDidMount()`, as John Ruddell [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57565419/react-prevent-component-re-render-on-click-event/57565500#comment101592365_57565419)).

Comment: Thank you, glad to know I was at least close to being on the right track.